# Divide By 5 Up Counter 6 to 10

Tags: counter

How can I design a divide by 5 counter which counts from 6 and up to 10 then resets to 6. A normal divide by 5 counter is 3 bit counter which counts from 0 to 5 then resets to 0. I think my one should be 4 bit and require some changes so that it will not count from 0 to 5 but starts from 6 instead?

Comment: Is this a theory question or do you actually want to make it with some logic family or with an HDL?

Comment: I need to draw the circuit diagram, thus I want some ideas on how the counter should be designed

Comment: You really only need three bits (so three JK flip-flops and a few gates), but if you were building it from standard parts, you'd likely use a 4-bit synchronous counter with synchronous preset.

Comment: Use a standard divide by 5 and add 6 to the answer.

Comment: A "normal" divide by 5 counter would count from 0-4, not 0-5 as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit should provide what you need.  It uses a [74HCT191 counter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc190.pdf), with binary presets so the counter can be initialized to 6 with a reset pulse.  It then advances on each clock pulse, 7,8,9,10 and 11, but because of the decoding of the output for 11 (binary 1011) using the four-input AND gate, it resets back to 6 again.  The count of 11 will temporarily -- and we're talking nanoseconds -- appear on the output before it changes back to 6; that could be avoided with more logic if it is a problem.

This circuit could also be implemented using a [74HCT163 counter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc163-q1.pdf), since it also has preset inputs.

It would also be possible to do this with a 4-bit counter and a 4-bit full adder (such as a 74HCT283), as someone else suggested, but this would require an extra IC.  The problem with the very short race condition would still be present, as the counter would have to reset from 5 to 0 instead of 11 to 6.

[image]

The inverter could actually be eliminated, and the 4-input AND replaced by a 3-input one, as it is not actually necessary to decode bit 2 (QC).  The counter can be reset using the output 1x11, where x is either 0 or 1, this works because the counter will be reset at 1011 (11) and never reach 1111 (15).

If you need to implement this circuit using discrete flip-flops rather than a using timer chip like the '191 or '163 chip, I suggest looking at the logic diagram for the 74HCT163. It is a little simpler than the 74HCT191.  There are also plenty of circuits on the web; for example the beginning of [this article](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_3.html) has a binary 4-bit synchronous up counter; you would just need to add the preset logic.

Answer (score 1):

A normal approach I would follow ( I dont know if there's an easier way; even I'm a student) is this :

1) Make a table. This table would consist of a column of Present state ( of 4 bits) starting from 0110 ( for decimal 6) and ending at 1010 ( for decimal 10).

2) Add a column of Next states. So corresponding to each state, you have a next state. For example, corresponding to 0110, the next state is 0111( for decimal 7) and corresponding to 1010, you have 0110 ( back to 6 again).

3) For each of the bits in the next state, make a corresponding K-map. Say you label the bits DCBA (in Present state column) and D'C'B'A' (in Next state column). You would make 4 maps, one each for D' , C' , B' , A' which would represent these in terms of Present state DCBA .

4) Simplify the k-maps and obtain an expression for each of the next states in terms of Present state.

5) Use Logic gates and flip flops to realize the expression you just obtained.

(Tedious I know, but I dont know of an easier way).